# Should last statement be `return` in and non void return types method?

Tags: java, return

Should last statement be `return` in and non void return types method? But this is still working.

```
public String test()
{
    try
    {
        // Do my work
        return "myValue";
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("I'm in Finally");
    }
}
```

I'm bit lack of knowledge to understand how this work. Could someone explain me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem with this code, because every possible path through it inevitably leads to a `return` statement<sup>*</sup>. It does not have to be the last statement textually, as long as it is the last statement logically (Java compiler is smart enough to figure out if it's so, and give you an error if there are paths through your code that do not return a value or throw an exception). The fact that there will be code executing after hitting the `return` (i.e. your `finally` block) does not change anything: as far as the compiler is concerned, your function has provided a return value before exiting the function.

<sup>*</sup> In fact, there is only one path through your function's code, and it terminates at the `return` statement.

Comment: @SamWard Absolutely - thank you very much for the correction!

Comment: The fun part is when you add a `catch` and don't rethrow. Then things get a bit more interesting :-) (See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13977143/129655)

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Well, that would create another path through your code, which must be covered.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yup, that's the point. I'm just trying to help you explore the question from another angle :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient in Java to make sure that all possible code paths either return a value or throw an exception. For example, the following code is valid:

```
public boolean test() {
    if (3 < 5) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Holy crap!");
    }
}
```

In your example, your `try` block ends with a return, so the happy path is covered and there is no need for code beyond the `finally`; in addition, any exceptions thrown in the `try` will propagate out of the method and will have no chance to reach the end of the method, so all possible paths will never hit the section under the `finally` block and no return statement is needed. (In fact, a compiler may give you a warning or error about unreachable code if you added a `return` statement at the bottom!)

Things change when you add a `catch` clause, because now it's possible for code to flow beyond the `try`/`catch`/`finally` block:

```
public String test(){
    try{

        // Do my work

        return "myValue";

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("O noes something went wrong");
        // swallow exception
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("I'm in Finally");
    }

    // Oh no! If an exception was caught, code can actually flow through here.
    // Compiler will complain about a missing return statement until you add one.
    // return "someOtherValue";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case `try` and `finally` always execute. So, it doesn't matter where is `return`.

```
public String myfun(){
    return "here";
}

or 

public String myfun(){
    try{
         return "here";
    }finally{
         //will execute always
    }
}
```

Are almost same. When, you see the flow of program. But, if there would be any conditional like

```
 public String myfun(){
      if(x==1){
           return "here";
      }
      else{
           // something here 
      }
 }
```

In this case, it will **raise error**. Since, either any of the block will execute not both. Same as

```
public String fun(){
     try{
          return "here";
     }
     catch(Exception e){
          //catch implementation without return
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not a very clear answer. Add a single `catch` clause that doesn't rethrow, for example: what happens then?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure just wait for few minutes.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Now, check my answer and let me know.

Comment: Looks better, though it could still use some editing for code indentation and/or clarity. I wasn't aware you were going to edit earlier, so I apologize if my first comment was too quick.

Answer (score 1):

The key JLS concept for this is [Normal and Abrupt Completion of Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1), combined with the behavior of [try-finally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).

The try block completes abruptly because of the return of "myValue". The finally block completes normally, so the whole try statement completes abruptly due to the same cause as the try block, return of "myValue".

In effect, the last statement in the method, the try statement, is one that returns a String.